# getEthToTokenInputPrice miner hack?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, mining, contract-invocation

Plan to use getEthToTokenInputPrice in a Dapp. I was going to just use a larger sample size spread out over a large time period to mitigate flash loan price manipulation. Someone said this was insufficient because miners could re-order things like so

1: miner dumps the price on Uniswap
2: miner lets the Dapp record the getEthToTokenInputPrice
3: miner reverses his transaction and only pays minor fees
4: The manipulated Uniswap price sticks in the Dapp even after the miner canceled the transaction

Was I given bad advice? This seems impossible how can a Dapp internalize data from a reversed transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you use price data and oracles that are on a blockchain, those will be rolled back as well if there is a chain reorganization.

If your dApp uses some traditional database and techniques to track the price then you need to roll back your price when the chain tip changes.